# Cannot select the search suggestion

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a search bar and for some reason i cannot select the search suggestions when i am typing, i have tried editing the list and some other methods but it doesnt work

Below is the snippet of my code.

```js
var searchIndex = ["404 Error", "Address Bar", "Ajax", "Apache", "Autoresponder", "BitTorrent", "Blog", "Bookmark", "Bot", "Broadband", "Captcha", "Certificate", "Client", "Cloud", "Cloud Computing", "CMS", "Cookie", "CSS", "Cyberspace", "Denial of Service", "DHCP", "Dial-up", "DNS Record", "Domain Name", "Download", "E-mail", "Facebook", "FiOS", "Firewall", "FTP", "Gateway", "Google", "Google Drive", "Gopher", "Hashtag", "Hit", "Home Page", "HTML", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "Hyperlink", "Hypertext", "ICANN", "Inbox", "Internet", "InterNIC", "IP", "IP Address", "IPv4", "IPv6", "IRC", "iSCSI", "ISDN", "ISP", "JavaScript", "jQuery", "Meta Search Engine", "Meta Tag", "Minisite", "Mirror", "Name Server", "Packet", "Page View", "Payload", "Phishing", "POP3", "Protocol", "Scraping", "Search Engine", "Social Networking", "Socket", "Spam", "Spider", "Spoofing", "SSH", "SSL", "Static Website", "Twitter", "XHTML"];

var input = document.getElementById("searchBox"),
  ul = document.getElementById("searchResults"),
  inputTerms, termsArray, prefix, terms, results, sortedResults;


var search = function() {
  inputTerms = input.value.toLowerCase();
  results = [];
  termsArray = inputTerms.split(' ');
  prefix = termsArray.length === 1 ? '' : termsArray.slice(0, -1).join(' ') + ' ';
  terms = termsArray[termsArray.length - 1].toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < searchIndex.length; i++) {
    var a = searchIndex[i].toLowerCase(),
      t = a.indexOf(terms);

    if (t > -1) {
      results.push(a);
    }
  }

  evaluateResults();
};

var evaluateResults = function() {
  if (results.length > 0 && inputTerms.length > 0 && terms.length !== 0) {
    sortedResults = results.sort(sortResults);
    appendResults();
  } else if (inputTerms.length > 0 && terms.length !== 0) {
    ul.innerHTML = '<li>Whoah! <strong>' +
      inputTerms +
      '</strong> is not in the index. <br><small><a href="http://google.com/search?q=' +
      encodeURIComponent(inputTerms) + '">Try Google?</a></small></li>';

  } else if (inputTerms.length !== 0 && terms.length === 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    clearResults();
  }
};

var sortResults = function(a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf(terms) < b.indexOf(terms)) return -1;
  if (a.indexOf(terms) > b.indexOf(terms)) return 1;
  return 0;
}

var appendResults = function() {
  clearResults();

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedResults.length && i < 5; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
      result = prefix +
      sortedResults[i].toLowerCase().replace(terms, '<strong>' +
        terms +
        '</strong>');

    li.innerHTML = result;
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  if (ul.className !== "term-list") {
    ul.className = "term-list";
  }
};

var clearResults = function() {
  ul.className = "term-list hidden";
  ul.innerHTML = '';
};

input.addEventListener("keyup", search, false);
```

```css
.search-field,
.term-list {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arvo", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2a5ba3;
  text-shadow: #fff 1px 1px 0px, #ddd 2px 2px, #ddd 3px 3px 1px;
}

.search-field {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-family: "Arvo", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3e8ce0;
}

.term-list {
  list-style: none inside;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
  padding: 5px 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: #777;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: "Arvo", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.term-list li {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.term-list strong {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">AutoComplete Me</h1>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" class="search-field" autoFocus />
<ul id="searchResults" class="term-list hidden"></ul>
```

Comment: have you tried replacing the UL with datalist? I have created a few search boxes like this and I use datalist not UL. I haven't attempted it with your code but that might be the fix

Comment: You are missing an event listener on your added li's.

Comment: i changed it to datalist but it doesnt work

Answer (score 5):

Use below code after `for` loop in `appendResults` functions

```
$('li').click(function(e) 
{ 
    $('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

```js
var searchIndex = ["404 Error", "Address Bar", "Ajax", "Apache", "Autoresponder", "BitTorrent", "Blog", "Bookmark", "Bot", "Broadband", "Captcha", "Certificate", "Client", "Cloud", "Cloud Computing", "CMS", "Cookie", "CSS", "Cyberspace", "Denial of Service", "DHCP", "Dial-up", "DNS Record", "Domain Name", "Download", "E-mail", "Facebook", "FiOS", "Firewall", "FTP", "Gateway", "Google", "Google Drive", "Gopher", "Hashtag", "Hit", "Home Page", "HTML", "HTTP", "HTTPS", "Hyperlink", "Hypertext", "ICANN", "Inbox", "Internet", "InterNIC", "IP", "IP Address", "IPv4", "IPv6", "IRC", "iSCSI", "ISDN", "ISP", "JavaScript", "jQuery", "Meta Search Engine", "Meta Tag", "Minisite", "Mirror", "Name Server", "Packet", "Page View", "Payload", "Phishing", "POP3", "Protocol", "Scraping", "Search Engine", "Social Networking", "Socket", "Spam", "Spider", "Spoofing", "SSH", "SSL", "Static Website", "Twitter", "XHTML"];

var input = document.getElementById("searchBox"),
  ul = document.getElementById("searchResults"),
  inputTerms, termsArray, prefix, terms, results, sortedResults;


var search = function() {
  inputTerms = input.value.toLowerCase();
  results = [];
  termsArray = inputTerms.split(' ');
  prefix = termsArray.length === 1 ? '' : termsArray.slice(0, -1).join(' ') + ' ';
  terms = termsArray[termsArray.length - 1].toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < searchIndex.length; i++) {
    var a = searchIndex[i].toLowerCase(),
      t = a.indexOf(terms);

    if (t > -1) {
      results.push(a);
    }
  }

  evaluateResults();
};

var evaluateResults = function() {
  if (results.length > 0 && inputTerms.length > 0 && terms.length !== 0) {
    sortedResults = results.sort(sortResults);
    appendResults();
  } else if (inputTerms.length > 0 && terms.length !== 0) {
    ul.innerHTML = '<li>Whoah! <strong>' +
      inputTerms +
      '</strong> is not in the index. <br><small><a href="http://google.com/search?q=' +
      encodeURIComponent(inputTerms) + '">Try Google?</a></small></li>';

  } else if (inputTerms.length !== 0 && terms.length === 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    clearResults();
  }
};

var sortResults = function(a, b) {
  if (a.indexOf(terms) < b.indexOf(terms)) return -1;
  if (a.indexOf(terms) > b.indexOf(terms)) return 1;
  return 0;
}

var appendResults = function() {
  clearResults();

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedResults.length && i < 5; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li"),
      result = prefix +
      sortedResults[i].toLowerCase().replace(terms, '<strong>' +
        terms +
        '</strong>');

    li.innerHTML = result;

    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    $('input').val($(this).text());
  });
  if (ul.className !== "term-list") {
    ul.className = "term-list";
  }
};

var clearResults = function() {
  ul.className = "term-list hidden";
  ul.innerHTML = '';
};

input.addEventListener("keyup", search, false);
```

```css
.search-field,
.term-list {
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.title {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3em 0 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Arvo", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #2a5ba3;
  text-shadow: #fff 1px 1px 0px, #ddd 2px 2px, #ddd 3px 3px 1px;
}

.search-field {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
  padding: 0.5em 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-size: 130%;
  font-family: "Arvo", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #3e8ce0;
}

.term-list {
  list-style: none inside;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
  padding: 5px 10px 0;
  text-align: left;
  color: #777;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-family: "Arvo", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.term-list li {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.term-list strong {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="title">AutoComplete Me</h1>
<input type="text" id="searchBox" class="search-field" autoFocus />
<ul id="searchResults" class="term-list hidden"></ul>
```

Comment: this is good, but is there a way to make it like googles' that i can select from multiple options  easily by pressing up or down with my arrow key and continue typing, or any thing like that

Comment: [This](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete) and [This](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element) might help you.

Comment: do you have any other search that works like the one above, because the one up can use multi value. other searches when i type a word the suggestions dont come up again but the one above after typing the first word, the suggestions still works while i am wyping other words, that is why i needed that search to work. but do you have anything similar?

Comment: As this extends/changes your original question, I recommend you to ask a new question for that.